# Proof verification of a limit theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, real-numbers

Theorem:Every convergent sequence is bounded.
Proof:Suppose there is a convergent sequence $X=(x_n)$ with limit $x\in \mathbb R$ that is not bounded.Then for all $M>0$,we can find $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $|x_k|>M$. Now,given
$m\in \mathbb N$,$\exists s\in\mathbb N$ such that $|x_m|<|x_s|$ since if it is not true,then for all $n\in\mathbb N$,$|x_n|\leq |x_m|$ which would imply that the sequence is bounded which is contrary to our assumption. Let $\varepsilon >0$ . We can find $K\in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n\geq K $,$|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$. Take $M=|x|$,and $\exists l\in\mathbb N$  such that $|x_l|>|x|$.There must be at least one $n\geq K$ such that
$|x|<|x_l|<|x_n|$(because we can get infinite number of such $|x_i|$ using the previous argument)  and thus $$|x_n|-|x|\leq |x_n-x|<\varepsilon$$ which means $|x_n|<|x|+\varepsilon$. This contradicts our assumption that the sequence is unbounded.Thus,the proof.
Please help me verify the glitches in it.

Comment: A proof by contradiction seems overcomplicated for this property.

Comment: Can I shorten it?

Comment: You have a shorter (and direct) proof  simply using the definition of the limit.

Comment: Is it correct ? I want to make sure it does not end up being absurd.

Comment: It does not work since you proved that $|x_n|<|x|+\varepsilon$ only for one $n$. A proof by contradiction is not the best way to do it, a much simpler argument would be to use de definition of the limit with, for instance, $\varepsilon=1$.

Comment: No, logically, it is correct, but overcomplicated

Comment: Ah!I can see the proof. If I use the inequality related to absolute values.

Comment: @Tuvasbien you are right.I have not actually shown it.But I found a way to complete it.

Comment: We can replace $\varepsilon$ by $|x_l|-|x|$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: Is it now fixed?